Альтернатива QwtPlotMarker
Изучаю библиотеку Qwt. Необходимо перемещать маркер динамически по пикселям (расчёт значения происходит в enableMagnifier). При попытке передвинуть текущий маркер по оси Х происходят рывки (их видно при масштабе для графика из 5000 точек, а также для большего масштаба, если масштаб уменьшить, появляется плавность хода маркера). Подозреваю, что QwtPlotMarker не предназначен для динамического использования, либо я неправильно обновляю элементы на QwtPlot.
mainwindow.h
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
 
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include "math.h"
 
#include <qwt_counter.h>
#include <qwt_plot.h>
#include <qwt_plot_grid.h>
 
#include <qwt_legend.h>
 
#include <qwt_plot_curve.h>
#include <qwt_symbol.h>
 
#include <qwt_plot_magnifier.h>
 
#include <qwt_plot_panner.h>
 
#include <qwt_plot_picker.h>
#include <qwt_picker_machine.h>
 
#include <qwt_plot_marker.h>
 
#include <qwt_scale_div.h>
#include <qwt_column_symbol.h>
 
 
namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
 
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
 
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
 
 
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
 
    QwtPlot *d_plot;
    void setPlot();
 
    QwtPlotGrid *grid;
    void setPlotGrid();
 
    QwtPlotCurve *curve;
 
    void setCurveParameters();
 
    QPolygonF points;
    QVector<double> dVecPointsY;
    QVector<double> dVecPointsX;
    void addPointsToCurveAndShow();
 
    QwtPlotMagnifier *magnifier;
    void enableMagnifier();
 
    QwtPlotPanner *d_panner;
    void enableMovingOnPlot();
 
    QwtPlotPicker *d_picker;
    void enablePicker();
 
    QToolBar *toolBar;
    void setToolBar();
 
    double changeXValue;
 
    QPushButton *choiceMarkerButton;
    void addChoiceMarkerButton();
 
    QPushButton *changeStepButton;
    void addChangeStepButton();
 
    QPushButton *moveMarkerButton;
    void addMoveMarkerButton();
 
    QwtPlotMarker *markerA;
    QwtPlotMarker *markerB;
 
    double dPositionMarkerA = 0;
    double dPositionMarkerB = 0;
 
    int iCurrentMarker = 0;
 
    double dCurrentStep;
 
    QVector <QwtPlotMarker*> vecMarkers;
    QVector <double> dVecPosition;
 
 
private Q_SLOTS:
    void click_on_canvas(const QPoint &pos);
    void choiceMarker();
    void moveMarker();
};
 
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H

mainwindow.cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
 
 
 
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
 
    setPlot();
 
    setPlotGrid();
 
    setCurveParameters();
    addPointsToCurveAndShow();
 
    enableMagnifier();
 
    enableMovingOnPlot();
 
    enablePicker();
 
    connect( d_picker, SIGNAL( appended( const QPoint & ) ),
        SLOT( click_on_canvas( const QPoint & ) ) );
 
    setToolBar();
 
    dVecPosition.append(dPositionMarkerA);
    dVecPosition.append(dPositionMarkerB);
 
    markerA = new QwtPlotMarker();
    markerA->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
    markerA->setLinePen(Qt::black, 2, Qt::SolidLine);
    markerA->setXValue(dVecPosition[iCurrentMarker]);
    markerA->attach(d_plot);
 
    markerB = new QwtPlotMarker();
    markerB->setLineStyle(QwtPlotMarker::VLine);
    markerB->setLinePen(Qt::red, 2, Qt::SolidLine);
    markerB->setXValue(dVecPosition[iCurrentMarker]);
    markerB->attach(d_plot);
 
    vecMarkers.append(markerA);
    vecMarkers.append(markerB);
 
    addChoiceMarkerButton();
 
    addMoveMarkerButton();
 
    connect(choiceMarkerButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(choiceMarker()));
    connect(moveMarkerButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(moveMarker()));
}
 
void MainWindow::choiceMarker() {
    qDebug() << "choice";
 
    if(iCurrentMarker == 0)
        ++iCurrentMarker;
    else
        --iCurrentMarker;
}
 
void MainWindow::addChoiceMarkerButton()
{
    choiceMarkerButton = new QPushButton("ChoiceMarker");
 
    toolBar->addWidget(choiceMarkerButton);
}
 
void MainWindow::addMoveMarkerButton() {
    moveMarkerButton = new QPushButton("Move");
 
    moveMarkerButton->setAutoRepeatInterval(0);
 
    moveMarkerButton->setAutoRepeat(true);
 
    toolBar->addWidget(moveMarkerButton);
}
 
void MainWindow::moveMarker() {
    //dCurrentStep = setterStep->value();
 
    vecMarkers.at(iCurrentMarker)->setXValue(vecMarkers.at(iCurrentMarker)->xValue() + dCurrentStep);
 
    qDebug() << "dCurrentStep: " << dCurrentStep;
 
}
 
 
 
 
void MainWindow::setToolBar()
{
    toolBar = new QToolBar( this );
 
    addToolBar(toolBar);
}
 
void MainWindow::setPlot()
{
    d_plot = new QwtPlot( this );
 
    d_plot->setAutoReplot(true);
 
    setCentralWidget(d_plot);
 
    d_plot->setTitle("Qwt demonstration");
    d_plot->setCanvasBackground( Qt::white );
 
    d_plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::yLeft, "Y");
    d_plot->setAxisScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, 0,0.01);
    d_plot->setAxisTitle(QwtPlot::xBottom, "X");
    d_plot->insertLegend( new QwtLegend() );
}
 
void MainWindow::setPlotGrid()
{
    grid = new QwtPlotGrid();
    grid->setMajorPen(QPen( Qt::gray, 2 ));
    grid->attach( d_plot );
}
 
 
void MainWindow::setCurveParameters()
{
    curve = new QwtPlotCurve();
    curve->setPen( Qt::blue, 6 );
    curve->setRenderHint
        ( QwtPlotItem::RenderAntialiased, true );
}
 
 
void MainWindow::addPointsToCurveAndShow()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        dVecPointsY.append(qSin(i) / i);
    }
 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        points << QPointF(i, dVecPointsY.at(i));
    }
 
    curve->setSamples(points);
 
    curve->attach( d_plot );
}
 
 
void MainWindow::enableMagnifier()
{
    magnifier = new QwtPlotMagnifier(d_plot->canvas());
    magnifier->setMouseButton(Qt::MidButton);
 
    dCurrentStep = qAbs(d_plot->axisInterval(QwtPlot::xBottom).maxValue() - d_plot->axisInterval(QwtPlot::xBottom).minValue()) / d_plot->sizeHint().rwidth();
}
 
void MainWindow::enableMovingOnPlot()
{
    d_panner = new QwtPlotPanner( d_plot->canvas() );
    d_panner->setMouseButton( Qt::RightButton );
}
 
void MainWindow::enablePicker()
{
    d_picker =
            new QwtPlotPicker(
                QwtPlot::xBottom, QwtPlot::yLeft,
    QwtPlotPicker::CrossRubberBand,
    QwtPicker::AlwaysOn,
    d_plot->canvas() );
 
    d_picker->setRubberBandPen( QColor( Qt::red ) );
 
    d_picker->setTrackerPen( QColor( Qt::black ) );
 
    d_picker->setStateMachine( new QwtPickerDragPointMachine() );
}
 
 
void MainWindow::click_on_canvas(const QPoint &pos)
{
    double x = d_plot->invTransform(QwtPlot::xBottom, pos.x());
    double y = d_plot->invTransform(QwtPlot::yLeft, pos.y());
 
    QString info = "x= " + QString::number(x) +
    "; y = " + QString::number(y);
 
    statusBar()->showMessage(info);
}
 
 
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

